# Replace multiple elements in numpy array with 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In a given numpy array `X`:

```
X = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

I would like to replace indices `(2, 3)` and `(7, 8)` with a single element `-1` respectively, like:

```
X = array([1,2,-1,5,6,7,-1,10])
```

In other words, I replaced values at indices `(2, 3)` and `(7,8)` of the original array with a singular value.

Question is: Is there a numpy-ish way (i.e. without for loops and usage of python lists) around it? Thanks.

Note: This is NOT equivalent of replacing a single element in-place with another. Its about replacing multiple values with a "singular" value. Thanks.

Comment: @awiebe I don't think you get the point, the point is two replace two indexes in to one element.

Comment: No I don't have to be rude, but I don't know of a different shorthand for that expression, additionally this question is a duplicate which has been asked no less than 3 times.

Comment: @awiebe No this is asked zero times not including this on so far...

Comment: If you want a to specify a single value, you just specify a single value on the RHS

Comment: @awiebe Not sure what this means ... the question is looking for a numpy-ish way of replacing two entities in an array with a single entity (demo-ed by the examples too in which you can clearly see the size of array reduced by 2 elements).

Comment: Ah, I see the question was resizing the array, not replacing the value.  That makes more sense then how I read it.

Comment: @awiebe Yup, that's why that's no a dupliacte of this :-)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `np.put`:

```
np.put(X, [2,3,7,8], [-1,0]) # `0` can be changed to anything that's not in the array
print(X[X!=0]) # whatever You put as an number in `put`
```

So basically use `put` to do the values for the indexes, then drop the zero-values.

Or as @khan says, can do something that's out of range:

```
np.put(X, [2,3,7,8], [-1,np.max(X)+1])
print(X[X!=X.max()])
```

All Output:

```
[ 1  2 -1  5  6  7 -1 10]
```

Comment: what if the list contains 0 initially?

Comment: This zero can actually be anything out of the range of the array..that will help it. So, `X=numpy.arange(1,11); numpy.put(X, [2,3,7,8], [-1,numpy.max(X)+1]); X[X!=X.max()]`..

Comment: A food for thought: What if we like to replace indices `(2,3,7,8)` with `-1` and indices `(9,10)` with `-2`..

Comment: @khan Then add an extra `put`, for indexes `9,10`

Comment: Thats true. Agreed.

Answer (score 7):

A solution using `numpy.delete`, similar to @pault, but more efficient as it uses pure numpy indexing.  However, because of this efficient indexing, it means that you cannot pass jagged arrays as indices

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
idx = np.stack([[2, 3], [7, 8]])
```

---

```
a[idx] = -1
np.delete(a, idx[:, 1:])
```

```
array([ 1,  2, -1,  5,  6,  7, -1, 10])
```

Comment: Definitely seems like a cleaner and more efficient way.

Comment: This is a very good approach. It avoids an extra lookup, because indices to be deleted are already know.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this can be done in one step, but here's a way using `np.delete`:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

X = np.array(range(1,11))
to_replace = [[2,3], [7,8]]


X[list(map(itemgetter(0), to_replace))] = -1
X = np.delete(X, list(map(lambda x: x[1:], to_replace)))
print(X)
#[ 1  2 -1  5  6  7 -1 10]
```

First we replace the first element of each pair with `-1`. Then we delete the remaining elements.